# Install autotest lib not found error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rubygems, autotest

I cannot get autotest to work. Rspec works fine.

Firstly, I cannot get the autotest/ Rspec command to work with the bundle exec command, so I modified the Gemfile to include the following code.

```
    source 'http://rubygems.org'

    gem 'rails', '3.0.7'
    gem 'sqlite3-ruby', '1.3.2', :require => 'sqlite3'

    group :development do
      gem 'rspec-rails', '2.5.0'
    end

    group :test do
    gem 'rspec', '2.5.0'
      gem 'webrat', '0.7.1'
    end

    group :development, :test do
      gem 'autotest'
    end
```

Then I tried installing autotest,

```
    $ [sudo] gem install autotest -v 4.4.6
```

I get the following error.

```
    Successfully installed autotest-4.4.6
    1 gem installed
    Installing ri documentation for autotest-4.4.6...
    File not found: lib
    ERROR:  While generating documentation for autotest-4.4.6
    ... MESSAGE:   exit
    ... RDOC args: --ri --op /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/doc/autotest-4.4.6/ri --main README.txt lib History.txt Manifest.txt README.txt --title autotest-4.4.6 Documentation --quiet
```

And subsequently I installed growl and fsevent

```
    $ [sudo] gem install autotest-rails-pure -v 4.1.2
    $ [sudo] gem install autotest-fsevent -v 0.2.4
    $ [sudo] gem install autotest-growl -v 0.2.9
```

These got installed

I modified the .autotest file in my root directory,

```
    require 'autotest-growl'
    require 'autotest-fsevent'
```

Now, when I try to run

```
    $ bundle exec autotest
```

I get the following error.

```
loading autotest/rspec2
/Users/toad/.autotest:1:in `require': no such file to load -- autotest/growl (LoadError)
    from /Users/toad/.autotest:1
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/ZenTest-4.5.0/lib/autotest.rb:311:in `load'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/ZenTest-4.5.0/lib/autotest.rb:311:in `initialize'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/ZenTest-4.5.0/lib/autotest.rb:310:in `each'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/ZenTest-4.5.0/lib/autotest.rb:310:in `initialize'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.5.2/lib/autotest/rspec2.rb:11:in `initialize'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/ZenTest-4.5.0/lib/autotest.rb:241:in `new'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/ZenTest-4.5.0/lib/autotest.rb:241:in `run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/ZenTest-4.5.0/bin/autotest:6
    from /usr/bin/autotest:19:in `load'
    from /usr/bin/autotest:19
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

`autotest-growl` is a separate gem from `autotest`, so you'll need a separate entry for it in your `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'autotest-growl'
```

You may need a separate `Gemfile` entry for `autotest-fsevent` too.